# C# Console app built using IRON Python. Executable of project to be run on Linux server

Tags: c#, linux, ironpython

I have made a simple c# console app which includes `IronPython` libraries. It accesses one simple python file which is included in the project and prints its contents.

It works fine on windows system. Then i moved my "exe and Python" script to the linux server and tried to run the command to execute the exe.

```
mono IronPythonTrial.exe
```

Below is my piece of code in C#

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IronPythonTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var py = Python.CreateEngine();
                Console.WriteLine("Engine Created");
                py.ExecuteFile(@"Script.py");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error" + ex.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

There is one pyhton file in the project directory "Script.py". Which will print one simple line.

The project has some of these libraries

```
IronPython 
IronPython.Modules
IronPython.SQLite 
Microsoft.Scripting
```

When I try and run the exe on linux server, I get unhandled exception about Microsoft.Scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it !!
Firstly installed Mono with Complete command !!
Also placed other required libraries on the linux server where the application was.

tahnks